# ng-show is not properly updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a loginpage based on the authentication i show/hide a div. Div use $scope.userdetails for showing or hiding.

```
<table class="txt_logged" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-show="{{userdetails}}">
```

Below is controller with watch method

```
.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope','SharedService',function($scope,SharedService)
{
    $scope.userdetails=SharedService.getUserDetails();

    $scope.$watch(function(){ return SharedService.getUserDetails()}, function(newValue, oldValue) 
    {
        if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) 
        {
            var t= SharedService.getUserDetails();
            if(t.toString()=="true")
            {
                $scope.userdetails =true;
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.userdetails =false;
            }

        }
    });

 }]);
```

why ng-show is not updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use it like:

```
<table class="txt_logged" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-show="userdetails">
```

`ngShow` evaluates the expression inside the attribute. If you put in a value `{{ userdetails }}`, it will evaluate to either `true` or `false`. This tries to search for a variable called `true` or `false`, inside `$scope`. The reason for evaluating the expression inside `ngShow` is so that you can use expressions without creating separate variables or if logic for displaying an element is overly complex:

```
<table class="txt_logged" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-show="xyz == 'true' && userdetails">
```

Also check out: [ngShow & ngHide](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide).

Comment: thanks it worked. Can u explain on why {{userdetails}} did not work.